Numeric Event Custom Parameter from GTM not being properly passed on to GA4
I'm tracking many events in GTM.
Most of them have custom parameters created and, in some cases, these parameters are passed through dataLayer and, among them, some collect numeric data (as opposed to strings). So, for example, I can have my dataLayer like this (extrated from Tag Assistant):
dataLayer.push({
  event: "generate_prg_search_datalayer",
  prgSrchKeyword: "",
  prgSrchSort: "Alphabetical order",
  prgSrchTheme: "Business",
  prgSrchCredentials: "Doctorate",
  prgSrchDelModels: "Blended",
  prgSrchStartDate: "",
  prgSrchResultCounter: "73",
  prgSrchPageNumber: "3",
})

Now, in my GTM, I have variables setup so, for example, variable div - prgSrchPageNumber is a dataLayer variable that grabs the value of prgSrchPageNumber, and so on.
And the Tag itself, when it fires, has a custom parameter (let's say prg_srch_pagenumber) that receives the value of the variable.
So, considering the dataLayer definition above, once the data arrives in GA4, the values are correct for all other parameters (prg_srch_theme, prg_srch_credentials, etc), except for the two parameters that receive numeric values (prg_srch_result_counter and prg_srch_page_number).
For some reason, this is true for all other events I created where the parameter is numeric in nature (for example, I have a parameter to pass on to GA4 the visitor selection of rows-per-page in a search result page - 10, 20, 50, etc), its value doesn't seem to be passed on to GA4 properly. When I try to report on it in Looker Studio, it's either "null" or have strange values like "auto3" or "-".
For all other parameters (where the value is a string), the reporting is as one would expected.
Does anyone know if there's anything special that has to be done in order to pass GTM parameters with numeric values to GA4?
Thanks,
Alex
